# How many odd $100$-digit numbers such that every two consecutive digits differ by exactly 2 are there?

Tags: combinatorics

## How many odd $100$-digit numbers such that every two consecutive digits differ by exactly 2 are there?

My first idea was to calculate the number of all odd $100$-digit numbers which use only odd digits, which equals $5^{100}$, and then try to subtract the number of all *bad* numbers, but I couldn't calculate it.

Then I tried to establish recurrence relation, but I don't even know where to start.

For example, all $3$-digit numbers which satisfy above condition: $135$, $131$, $313$, $353$, $357$, $535$, $531$, $575$, $579$, $757$, $753$, $797$, $975$, $979$ .

Please help!

Comment: Can you please give example of one such number?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot.
All $3$-digit numbers which satisfy above condition:
$135$, $131$, $313$, $353$, $357$, $535$, $531$, $575$, $579$, $757$, $753$, $797$, $975$, $979$ .

Comment: I take it you mean "differ in absolute value"?  So $202020\dots$ is a good example?

Comment: @tatan For instance, $13135753$, or $64246864$ for $8$ digits. It's like a bounded random walk.

Comment: Can you please clarify your question?  The number of odd $100$-digit numbers is NOT $5^{100}$.  And then you switch to three digits, which can easily be done by hand...

Comment: @lulu I think you missed the **odd** part....$202020...$ is not odd

Comment: @tatan  Right, so $313131\dots$   then.

Comment: @mivan PLease make the edit into the question...not in the comments....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To establish a recurrence relation you could proceed as follows (this is an answer not a comment for length, but won't solve the recurrence).

Let $a_n, b_n, c_n, d_n, e_n$ be respectively the number of $n$-digit numbers in your set beginning with the digits $1,3,5,7,9$ respectively. Then stripping the first digit gives $$a_n=b_{n-1}; b_n=a_{n-1}+c_{n-1}; c_n=b_{n-1}+d_{n-1};d_n=c_{n-1}+e_{n-1};e_n=d_{n-1}$$

Then observe that symmetry considerations give $a_n=e_n$ and $b_n=d_n$

This reduces the system to $3$ equations $$a_n=b_{n-1}$$$$ b_n=a_{n-1}+c_{n-1}$$$$ c_n=2b_{n-1}$$ and that immediately gives $c_n=2a_n$ and I'll leave it to you to solve from there, having got the system under some control.

Answer (score 0):

A direct recurrence is difficult, but if we count something different, then it becomes easier. For each of the five digits $d \in \{1,3,5,7,9\}$, and for each number length $n$, we can count the number $A(d,n)$ of numbers satisfying your constraint. For each $d$, we have $A(d,1) = 1$. For $n > 1$, we have $A(n,1) = A(n-1,3)$, and $A(n,9) = A(n-1,7)$, and for the other digits $d$, we have
$$
A(n,d) = A(n-1,d-2) + A(n-1,d+2).
$$
This is still tedious for a human to compute, but a very short computer program should make this easy.

Answer (score 0):

Define $D(n, e)$ as your number, length $n$ and ending with $e$.

$D(1, e) = 1, e \in \{1,3,5,7,9\}$

$D(n, 1) = D(n, 9) = D(n-1, 3)$

$D(n, 3) = D(n, 7) = D(n-1, 5) + D(n-1, 1)$

$D(n, 5) = D(n-1, 3) + D(n-1, 7) = 2*D(n-1, 3)$

Answer (score 0):

Let $a_n$, $b_n$, $c_n$, $d_n$, $e_n$ be the number of $n$-digit numbers whose digits are odd, any two consecutive digits differing by $2$, and ending
in $1$, $3$, $5$, $7$, $9$, respectively. Then

$\pmatrix{0&1&0&0&0\\1&0&1&0&0\\0&1&0&1&0\\0&0&1&0&1\\0&0&0&1&0} \pmatrix{a_n\\b_n\\c_n\\d_n\\e_n} = \pmatrix{a_n + 1\\b_n + 1\\c_n + 1\\d_n + 1\\e_n + 1}$.

Let $A$ be the square matrix in this expression. We wish to compute then eigenvalues of $A$, so suppose $A_v = \lambda_v$ for some vector $v = (v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4, v_5)$. Then

$v_2 = \lambda v_1$

$v_3 = \lambda v_2 - v_1 = (\lambda^2 - 1)v_1$

$v_4 = \lambda v_3 - v_2 = (\lambda^3 - 2\lambda)v_1$

$v_5 = \lambda v_4 - v_3 = (\lambda^4 - 3\lambda^2 + 1)v_1$

and $v_4 = \lambda v_5$, so $\lambda^5 - 3\lambda^3 + \lambda = \lambda^3 - 2\lambda$. Solving this polynomial gives $\lambda = 0, \pm 1, \pm \sqrt{3}$. The corresponding eigenvector $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$, $x_4$, $x_5$ are

$(1,0,-1,0,1), (1,1,0,-1,-1), (1,-1,0,1,-1), (1,\pm \sqrt{3},2,\pm \sqrt{3},1)$

and

$(1,1,1,1,1) = \dfrac13 x_1 \dfrac{2 + \sqrt{3}}{6}x_4 + \dfrac{2 - \sqrt{3}}{6}x_5$,

so

$(a_{1000},b_{1000},c_{1000},d_{1000},e_{1000}) = $

$3^{999/2} \dfrac{2 + \sqrt{3}}{6}(1, \sqrt{3},2,\sqrt{3},1) - \dfrac{2 - \sqrt{3}}{6}(1, - \sqrt{3},2,- \sqrt{3},1) = $

$(3^{499}, 2\cdot 3^{499}, 2\cdot 3^{499}, 2\cdot 3^{499}, 3^{499})$

Thus the answer is $8\cdot 3^{499}$.